# custom uitextfield with custom inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

is strange to se no question about this problem in all stack overflow, but i can't find it :(

So let me explain. I have a simple `UITextField` that should present a custom `inputAccessoryView`.

The expected behavior is:

1. tap in the textfield (ACTextField)
2. show keyboard with a textfield and a button (with cancel title)
3. type in some text (it have to appear in the `UITextField` named
   `inputField` )
4. press enter and see the text appearing in the main textfield

in case i press cancel the keyboard should disappear and let the main textfield unchenged

pretty much like the Message App from Apple

And all works well exept 2 things:

1. if i spam key tapping on the keyboard (just to enter random text ;)
   ) the app freeze and Xcode show me CPU at 99% (no recovery possible)
2. sometimes the memory occupation grow from 2/3 MB to 40 MB just after
   pressing enter and the app freeze again

Let's show some code
the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ACTextField : UITextField

@end
```

the .m

```
#import "ACTextField.h"

@interface ACTextField () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *inputField;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL keyboardOpen; // to check if keyboard is open
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer; //added after an answer

@end

@implementation ACTextField

// method called when timer fire
- (void) fireTimer:(NSTimer *) timer
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil; // this line thoesen't change anyting so can be deleted
    [self.inputField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self awakeFromNib];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.delegate = self;
    self.keyboardOpen = NO;
}

- (void)cancelPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.inputField resignFirstResponder];
    [self resignFirstResponder];

    self.keyboardOpen = NO;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc ACTextField %@", self);
    self.inputField = nil;
    self.timer = nil;
}

- (void) designAccessoryView
{
    if (self.inputAccessoryView == nil) {

        CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        self.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 44)];

        self.inputAccessoryView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        int buttonWidth = 65;
        int padding = 5;

        UIButton *cancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        cancel.frame = CGRectMake(padding, 0, buttonWidth, 44);
        [cancel setTitle:@"cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancel setTitle:@"cancel" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.inputAccessoryView addSubview:cancel];

        self.inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonWidth + 2*padding, 2, frame.size.width - buttonWidth - 3*padding, 40)];
        self.inputField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

        self.inputField.delegate = self;

        [self.inputAccessoryView addSubview:self.inputField];
        self.inputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (!self.keyboardOpen && textField == self)
    {
        self.inputField.text = self.text;
        [self designAccessoryView];

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                         target:self // modified to use the instance method fireTimer
                                       selector:@selector(fireTimer:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];

        self.keyboardOpen = YES;
    }
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    self.text = self.inputField.text;
    [self cancelPressed:self];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I forgot to specify that i'm testing this on my iPhone 4s with IOS 7.0.4

EDIT2: I tried using an `UITextField` Wrapper with pretty much the same code and all goes well. The behavior is the expected and the keyboard don't freeze anymore and the memory remain low as should be. Ok, but i need a `UITextField` subclass, not a wrapper :(

Comment: this is a bug in iOS simulator ... see the error in console

Comment: maybe, but the problem is on the device :(

Comment: `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001
                                         target:self.inputField
                                       selector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];` and this code used to prevent user close keyboard before he tap on cancel? This is potential problem. try to reduce time interval and check again

Comment: @SamBudda anyway i tried again, just to be sure, and console show nothing

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk Reduce? less time like 0.00000001 or more time like 0.1 ?

Comment: @Alex75, with 0.00000001 interval timer will fires 10000000 times per second (I dont know is it actually possible)

Comment: o :p but the timer should fire only once as i specified the parameter "repeats:NO". Anyway, now i'm using 0.1 and there r no changes :(

Comment: @Alex75, oops, sorry, my bad :) my answer is not actual. I'm usually use `performSelectorWithDelay:` or `dispatch_after` for delayed calls, so dont pay attention on repeats parameter.

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk performSelectorWithDelay and dispatch_after may be good instead of nstimer, never use them. I'll try